# Why would a web part fail on constructor the first time it's being added to a page?

Tags: sharepoint, exception, sharepoint-2007, moss, web-parts

This question is a bit specific (MOSS2007) and I don't high hopes for getting an answer, but maybe luck will smile upon me.

I have a web part that works except **the very first time** it's being added to a page. It throws an exception inside a **constructor** when I'm trying to open a connection to a SQL server. The demand for the SqlClientPermission permission fails. When I say it works, I mean it is properly registered in any regard and works in every other case, including subsequent calls.

Someone said there is no way out. I'd like to know why. Is it by design?

I went so far as to give a full trust to everything I could (changed **every** .config file I could find on my server), but it did not help.

It appears that SharePoint is doing some kind of remoting the first time it adds a web part, which appears to run with minimal trust the first time it's constructed (same as defined in web_minimaltrust.config for ASP.Net). Attempts to grant permissions for everything in everything did not yield any fruitful results.

My solution was to move the data access code to the OnInit method, but that is irritating. Does anyone have any insight?

Thank you.

Some extra info from the debugger.

The only permitted permissions were:

```
<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1">
    <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Flags="Execution"/>
    <IPermission class="System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Level="Minimal"/>
</PermissionSet>
```

The inner exception stack:

```
hresult = -2146233078
mscorlib
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
at System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand()
at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.DemandPermission()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
at IManageDocumentsPart.ClientSideDocumentsWebPart.GetOfficeCode(Int32 employeeId)
at IManageDocumentsPart.ClientSideDocumentsWebPart..ctor()
```

The full stack:

```
IManageDocumentsPart.DLL!IManageDocumentsPart.ClientSideDocumentsWebPart.ClientSideDocumentsWebPart() Line 98    C#
[Native to Managed Transition]    
[Managed to Native Transition]    
mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(bool publicOnly, bool fillCache = true) + 0x68 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, bool nonPublic) + 0x43 bytes    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.FastCreatePublicInstance(System.Type type) + 0x56 bytes    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManagerInternals.CreateObjectFromType(System.Type type) + 0x7 bytes    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager.ImportWebPart(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {EndElement, Name="metaData"}, out string errorMessage = null) + 0x35d bytes    
Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ImportWebPartBase(System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {EndElement, Name="metaData"}, string importErrorMessage = "Cannot import this Web Part.", out string errorMessage = null) + 0x25 bytes    
Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartImporter.CreateWebPart(bool clearConnections = true) + 0x1b4 bytes    
Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartImporter.Import(Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager manager = {Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager}, System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {None}, bool clearConnections = true, System.Uri webPartPageUri = {http://v-sp2007/testsite/default.aspx?PageView=Shared}, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb spWeb = {Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb}) + 0x8e bytes    
Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartImporter.Import(Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager manager = {Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager}, System.Xml.XmlReader reader = {None}, bool clearConnections = true, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb spWeb = {Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb}) + 0xa1 bytes    
Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartQuickAdd.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument = "http%253A%252F%252Fv%252Dsp2007%252F%255Fcatalogs%252Fwp%252FClientSideDocumentsWebPart%252Ewebpart;ClientSideDocumentsWebPart") + 0x288 bytes    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, string eventArgument) + 0xc bytes    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postData) + 0xb2 bytes
```

...the rest of the stack is the same as when opening a page normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a reference for the next ones coming, [here](http://www.thorprojects.com/blog/archive/2008/04/16/web-part-event-firings-and-why-you-shouldn%E2%80%99t-have-code-in-the-constructor.aspx) there's one of the many articles were code in web part constructor is marked as a **big NO-NO**.

Comment: and yes, the constructor might be called one first time, without all the security objects set up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting up a solution package to deploy code access security settings.  You definitely need SqlClientPermission.  Check out my post on [Code Access Security for web parts](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2007/07/05/how-to-configure-code-access-security-for-a-web-part.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. However, I have. I tried with it and without. And issue here is not that CAS is misconfigured, since if it was nothing would work at all. It's that SharePoint disregards any configuration and runs w/min trust when first time adding a web part.

Answer (score 1):

That is odd.  Maybe you could special case your web part to not do the database call when the page is in edit/design mode.  Wouldn't that fix your problem?

Comment: I suppose I could do that. As I mentioned, I moved the code into OnInit and that "fixed" it. I just want to know why does it run a constructor with a minimal set of permissions when I granted all.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple test, you could deploy the assemby containing the web part into the GAL.  There it will run with Full Trust.

Personally, I would not recommend establishing a database connection in the constructor of a web part unless you had a compelling reason to do so.

[updated 3009-03-27]

Debugging is often about ruling out causes.  Even though you believe the web part is running in Full Trust, I recommend testing the GAC'ed case.  Remember to remove the .dll from the Bin directory for the test.  This will only take 5-10 minutes and you'll *know* where you stand.

Comment: I haven't tried GAL yet, since the web part runs in FullTrust, just not when added the first time. I will try. I access DB in the constructor because certain design-time properties are dependent on user specific data. However, any privileged method fails, not just DB.

Answer (score 1):

> My solution was to move the data access code to the OnInit method, but that is irritating. Does anyone have any insight?

When SharePoint is going through and processing the request the first thing that it will be doing is executing your constructor to create a new instance of the object.  The Constructors that it calls are parameterless so that they can be serialized and deserialized for import/exports.  Inside of the constructor none of the security constructs or associated objects have been set in the newly created object.  It may therefore be the case that your object does not have any context information about where it is living or what it is doing.

By moving your code into the OnInit method you have shifted the time of execution back as some of your related objects and what not have been bound automatically by this point.  In the ASP.net lifecycle, OnInit methods work from the from the top down and OnLoad methods work from the bottom up.  So that may also influence whether your parent or children have had their related code executed yet.